# Plotting point on a curve and a circle. Then, connect those points

Tags: plotting

I have a curve and a circle on x,y axes. I want to plot points on the curve and on the circle based on the "a". The value of "a" should be {1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5} of the curve and the circle. Then, I want to connect those points on curve and the circle. I've been working on this for several days but still couldn't found the solution.

`Quad1 = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}};(*Define 3 control points for the polygon*)
Print[MatrixForm[Quad1]]
q1 = Graphics[BezierCurve[Quad1]]; (*Construct a Bezier Curve*)
a = BezierFunction[Quad1]
Show[Graphics[{Red, Point[Quad1], Green, Line[Quad1]}, Axes -> True], 
 ParametricPlot[a[t], {t, 0, 1}], 
 ParametricPlot[{{ Cos[t], Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotStyle -> Orange, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}]]
a1 = a[1/5]
a2 = a[2/5]
a3 = a[3/5]
a4 = a[4/5]`

[image]

Comment: Firstly, what's Quad1?

Comment: Quad1 is the control points for the bezier curve. (blue curve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Quad1 = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}};

a = BezierFunction[Quad1];

pts1 = a /@ Range[1/5, 4/5, 1/5];

pts2 = {Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@
   (Pi Range[4/5, 1/5, -1/5]);

Show[
 ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}],
 ParametricPlot[a[t], {t, 0, 1}],
 Epilog -> {
   AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Green,
   Line[Quad1],
   Red,
   Point[pts1],
   Point[pts2],
   Dashed,
   Line /@ Transpose[{pts1, pts2}]}]
```

[image]